# Windows 7 x64 wired connection problem. IP, gateway, dns assigned, can't ping. Network detected as "Network"

Tags: windows-7, networking, 64-bit

I am having a problem connecting to a specific wired network with my Latitude E6410 laptop.  Other wired networks seem to work fine, but this one does not.  I have a coworker with me with the same Intel 82577LM Gigabit Network card, and he can connect just fine.  I've updated to the latest Intel drivers (11.8.75.0) and am not using Pro Set.

I obtain all DHCP information just fine (IP, netmask, DNS server, default gateway).  I cannot ping anything (internal or on the Internet - I tried pinging Google's public DNS servers by IP 8.8.8.8), nor can I get answers to any DNS queries through NS Lookup.  Windows troubleshooting says everything is fine, but I can't get DNS responses.

I've seen issues like this in the past that were related to link speed/duplex autonegotiaion failures, so I've tried manually setting link speed/duplex to all values one by one with no success.  My coworker is using all default settings, so he is just using autonegotiate.

Any ideas of other things to try?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about the networking environment? Type of internet connection, ISP equipment, routers, switches, etc along the way?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections"
If there is anything else except your Network Connection?
If so, try disabling them and then give the ping maybe you have a conflict between your adapters.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I already gave that a go and it didn't help.